# I want a regular expression that accepts arabic characters as well as arabic and english numbers

Tags: php, regex

Im running a php code and I want to validate data using a regular expression that accepts arabic characters as well as arabic and english numbers , it should also accepts white spaces and new lines as well as arabic punctuations such as ، .

Comment: You need to provide details of what you tried and what is not working in your solution.

Comment: I tried this one ^[\p{Arabic}\s\p{N}]+$  but I dont think it's working for all the things I've mentioned above in my question

Comment: Yes, that looks good. You can either add specific characters that don't match at the moment or invert the logic and instead specify what you need to exclude. Maybe you also need to add /u (if your string is UTF-8) and /s modifiers (if you're having problem with matching newlines)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

Add Arabic letters and allowed characters such as commas

```
preg_match('/^[ ٫ ، . ۰-۹ 0-9 آابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیئؤء]+$/', $value);
```